# C++ right way of returning a generic collection of type

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, generics, containers

I'm new to C++, and unfortunately I cannot stop thinking in C# (my former language).
I read some books, forums and the C++ reference website, but I couldn't find an answer to my question, so I thought I might as well try here before giving up and writing something ugly.

Ok, we can start.
I have a class with an abstract method **succesorsFunction** and I would like it to return a collection of pointers to **State**. I don't want to force the implementors to a specific container; I rather let them choose (vector, list, etc).

So it looks like this:

```
class Problem
{
public:
    virtual list<const State*>::iterator succesorsFunction(const State &state, list<const State*>::iterator result) const = 0;
};
```

the problem here is the explicit use of list. How do you do it in C++?

I thought about using templates, but then I encountered two problems:
1) It seems like you cannot do it with abstract methods (or am I wrong?)
2) How do I tell the template it should contain pointers to State?

Comment: Boost.Range's type-erased ranges may help here.

Comment: Can you expand on what this function and it being virtual is supposed to achieve? There might be alternative approaches.

Comment: So you would like to return something analogous to `IEnumerable<State>`?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche 'Problem' is an interface. What I really want to do is to return a generic container instead of a concrete one.

Comment: @svic exactly. I feel like I shouldn't try to do that in C++, but how do you do return a collection of a certain type?

Comment: But what is the function supposed to do? Why can't it be a free function? I.e. you are asking how to fix your approach instead of how to solve the actual problem.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche OK. there's a search algorithm, that gets a problem and return a solution. I want to write the whole search architecture without writing to a concrete problem, but to interfaces. One of the components of the problem is a functions that gets a State and return its successors (states reachable from the state in the search tree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overload methods based on return types in C++.

Also, "containers" in C++ don't have the same base (like `Collection` in Java), so you can't return a generic container.

I'm afraid there's no clean way of doing this.

I would just write overloads (by parameter) or different function names.

For your questions:

1) You can. What makes you think you can't?

2) The same way you declared `list`: `list<const State*>` - `const` is optional.

Comment: I don't think he said anything about overloading by return value; there are multiple implementations with the same return type. He just  wants the return type to be general enough not to restrict the implementation.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill his question says he wants to return a collection and he doesn't want to restrict the collection (although the code returns an iterator).

Comment: ... which doesn't say anything about overloading by return type.

Comment: I think 1) refers to templated virtual functions, which you *can't* do.

Comment: You can handle generic containers, you just need template functions taking iterators. 1) What Xeo said. 2) He meant generic containers.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I meant templated virtual functions (as Xeo said). I used iterator because I thought this is how you do it in C++. Is there really no clean way of doing it?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche so I should give up the abstraction of the method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a member function template which is virtual, but you can try implement friend generic function like this:

```
template <typename yourType>
yourType& succesorsFunction(const State &a, yourType &result){//Your return type can be without reference
    //Your body
    return result;
}
```

If you call your function for example with `vector<State> a` argument like this:

```
sucessorsFunction(b,a);// b is your State object
```

deduction process will automatically conclude that `yourType` is actually `vector<State>` type, which I think resolves your problem. Also, this arhitecture aloves you to create for example new class type MyVector (which holds arrays of `States`) and pass `MyVector` object to `succesorsFunction`.

Comment: I tried to do that but it didn't work with abstract method. I might as well remove the =0 at the end and get it over with. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @wolfovercats how would you populate result if you don't know the type?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I know the type; it's State*.

Comment: ok, I got what you meant. I will use push_back(). this way they can still choose between vector, list and a queue. ok, maybe I should just restrict it to a vector; i'm not sure it's worth all the trouble

Comment: That's what I mean. A base `Collection` would be great, you could just `add` elements to anything. In C++, you need to push_back or add or insert or etc... You *could* specialize this function, but I don't think it's worth the hassle.

Comment: I edited my post. It seems you can't have a member function template which is virtual.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to enforce STL container usage, try the following:

```
template <template <typename, 
                    typename = std::allocator<const State *> > class Container>
 Container<const State*> successorsFunction(const State &state, const Container<const State*> &c) const
 {
    // return something useful.
 }
```

If you insist on having this function be virtual, then it can't be a member function template, just overload it with the types you intend to support, then you can make them virtual.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an elaboration to [C.T's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9440829/124797) answer. Please remember that if you return a container of pointers then you will have to release them explicitly or use `std::unique_ptr` .
Just a FYI.. as you are from C# background.

You could use State or templatize it as well.

```
template<typename Type, 
         template< typename, typename = std::allocator<Type*> > class Container 
        >
Container<Type*> Successor(const Type& x)
{
    Container<Type*> cont;
    // something.
    cont.push_back(new Type(x));
    return cont;   
}
```

and call it

```
vector<State*> states = Successor<State, vector>(State(10));
```